# My downloaded file is changing its name to 'download' although I changed it in the headers

Tags: php

I'm trying to make 2 option names to download a file: Dictionary and Random.
When the user selects the dictionary option it downloads the file constantly with the name 'download' instead of some random word from the dictionary and the random option works fine.

I tried using the load function and printing what it returns and it does print the actual randomly picked word from the dictionary but it doesn't in the download part. I'm guessing its something with the headers but it might not.

That's the load function which loads the dictionary from a file on the server:

```
function load($file) {
   $file_arr = file($file);
   $num_lines = count($file_arr);
   $last_arr_index = $num_lines - 1;
   $rand_index = rand(0, $last_arr_index);
   $rand_text = $file_arr[$rand_index];
   return $rand_text;
}
```

That's the download function which downloads the file:

```
function download($file, $filename) {
   header("Content-Type: application/jpeg");
   header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

   readfile($file);
   exit();
}
```

That's how I call the functions:

```
  $filename = load("includes/dictionary_words.txt");
  download($file, $filename);
```

Lastly the $file variable:

```
  $file = "main/app.exe";
```

Instead of downloading the file with a random dictionary name it downloads it with a 'download' name. I didn't get any errors or notices.

Comment: What happens when you `curl -D headers.txt ...` it?

Comment: @barrycarter What do you mean?

Comment: Oh, run that command from your machine with the URL of your site. It will show you what headers are being sent. You might also be able to use your browser's web developer tools. I suspect the headers you're trying to send aren't actually being sent.

Comment: The first two headers and the first part of the third works but the filename attribute in the headers doesn't although it does work for the Random function it doesn't for the dictionary one

Comment: I'm reaching here, but maybe the browser (or something) doesn't like "application/jpeg" as a header for a file ending in.txt or something. Try "text/plain"

Comment: Tried it and still the filename is 'download' and also I don't know if that's what you said but the file is a .exe and the dictionary from which it chooses the word is a .txt